# Credit card payments via PayPal REST API without being PCI-compliant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Can't understand which PayPal API to use.

I have Rails app and I'd like to accept credit card recurring payments via PayPal. At first I was thinking to use **Express Checkout API** that supports recurring billing and can work even if a user doesn't have PayPal account. But then I saw that their official ruby gem `merchant-sdk-ruby` https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby will be deprecated:

> This Classic SDK is not actively supported and will be **deprecated** in
>   the future. For full support on new integrations, please use the **Ruby
>   Rest SDK**

So I don't want to use something that will be deprecated soon. But I can't understand whether I can use REST API to accept credit cards without being PCI-compliant.

I'd like to redirect user to PayPal where he could enter his credit card info and return back to my site like in Express Checkout, but I see only examples where credit card info is collected on my site and passed to PayPal via API that implies more security headache on my site.

**UPD:** I found some information regarding this question in [Accept a PayPal payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) section of **REST API** documentation that is a bit odd because I expected to find it in [Accept credit card payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/) section. They say:

> **Important**: To receive Guest Checkout payments, which allow credit cards, ensure that PayPal Account Optional is enabled on your account
>   settings. For example, here is the path for US accounts:
>   *Profile > My selling tools > Website preferences > PayPal Account Optional*

But I'm still not sure whether it will work in my case. Now I have the following question:

1. Can I use Guest Checkout feature to accept **recurring** payments?
2. Can I test Guest Checkout in **Sandbox**? And if I can what credit card number to use?
3. Can I show by default form for entering credit card info when user gets to the PayPal site rather than for entering PayPal credentials?

*Ughh... why it is so complicated?*

Comment: Do you have to use paypal or can you use alternatives like braintree, stripe, paymil or others?

Comment: If it is possible, I would stick with PayPal because it is more convinient for the site owner. It's API and docs are far from ideal, but they are not worst.

Comment: There is a good blogpost that explains simple paypal chackout in rails using redirect urls and has a followup for recurring payments... http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of samples in PHP code, that could help you understand recurring payment options in REST API.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/billing

Or you could follow up the docs on : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#billing-plans-and-agreements

1. I will look into this specifically and get back to you
2. For trying it out on sandbox, you can create an account here at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps You need to create an app, and it would generate a valid credit card for you.
3. This may be very unlikely to do, but I can ask the internal team if they know of any such option.

Answer (score 0):

Railscast #289 is on this. It requires that you sign up for the pro version. Looks pretty involved but he walks you through it.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen it already. Ryan is using `paypal-recurring` gem that wasn't updated for several years. It looks like REST API is more modern way to talk to PP, but I can't figure out whether there is option to enter credit card data on PayPal site without creating account there.